# Running powershell 7 script in asp net core web appllication

Tags: c#, powershell, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I would like to create an asp net web application and and I have found out that it requires that I can use Powershell 7, since I need to able to use the -parallel switch in a foreach-object loop I have in a script Ì am going to run.

I have managed to create an asp net framework web app but with that I`m using PS 5.

I need to click a button and fire off the PS script in the web app.
I have more scripts to run, and would like to seperate them in different button-clicks.

I have tried to use different nuget packages to reference them but I just cant seem to get it right.

I guess what I`m looking at is trying to use the System.Management.Automation assembly and using the Powershell class from that. Am I on the right way.
I guess also I will need the Microsoft.Powershell.SDK??

Have anyone done this for an asp net core web app and what kind of a project i Visual Studio have you used?
I`m using VS 2019.

What kind of approach have you done?

Tommy

Answer (score 0):

Is your webapp expecting any output when running the Powershell script? Or is it just a fire and forget?
If the latter, you could implement some type of event based integration, where the button is firing an event, and a script is listening to that.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for you question. We are expekting both an input and an output to/from the script. We expect to use both AddArgument and get the output after the Invoke.